# How to implement react-widgets dropdownlist in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-widgets

I am trying to add dropdownlist in my reactjs project. My data are coming from api which looks something like this. 
[image: data]

In dropdown list i have to display `colours` and `sizeType` in dropdown list.

I tried doing this but it is not working.

```
  const data = [props.data];
  return (
    <Grid xs={12} className="sort" container>
      <DropdownList
        style={{ height: "auto" }}
        placeholder={props.title}
        className="drop-down"
        data={data}
      />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Keep in mind every data that you want to put in dropdown should have a unique id, so you should either create it yourself and make an array of `colours` and `sizeType` or ask your backend developer to put each of them in the array with unique ids.

Comment: @SMAKSS can please suggest me a  way so that i can do it myself.

Comment: I just post an answer that may help you with it, please let me know if you got any problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we suppose that `props.data` you provided is the actual data that you received from API.

### Destructuring our actual data

Since the actual data is Object itself we can access the `colours` and `sizeType` property within them just like this:

```js
const colours = data.colours;
const sizeType = data.sizeType;
```

### Making an array of our destructured data

Since the `colours` and `sizeType` itself are string we should make an array of them to pass it to the `DropdownList` as the data, so we can do it as below:

```js
const coloursArray = data.colours.split(',');
const sizeTypeArray = data.sizeType.split(',');
```

**NOTE:** Keep in mind each array got his unique indexes so we don't have to create a unique id by ourself and the `DropdownList` will use it as it unique id for distinction, but the for using best practices we should provide the unique ids for each dropdown and data by using `UUID` to keep the distinction much more clear. For more information about `UUID`, you can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105074/11908502).

**NOTE 2:** Since the string attribute that we wanted are splitting with `,` we can simply use the comma symbol as the `split` function input. You can read more about the split function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

---

### Final output

So this will be the final return that you have provide for your component:

```
return (
    <Grid xs={12} className="sort" container>
      <DropdownList
        style={{ height: "auto" }}
        placeholder={props.title} //Title for colours dropdown
        className="drop-down"
        data={coloursArray}
      />
    </Grid>
    <Grid xs={12} className="sort" container>
      <DropdownList
        style={{ height: "auto" }}
        placeholder={props.title} //Title for colours dropdown
        className="drop-down"
        data={sizeTypeArray}
      />
    </Grid>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you should split your colors string to array

```
const colorsArray = data.colors.split(',');
```

then pass it like data attribute

```
  return (
    <Grid xs={12} className="sort" container>
      <DropdownList
        style={{ height: "auto" }}
        placeholder={props.title}
        className="drop-down"
        data={colorsArray}
      />
    </Grid>
```